# Can I give a path in URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, angular, blob, createobjecturl

I am opening a pdf in new tab using the below function:

```
const blob = new Blob([data.body], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
          });
```

```
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener');
```

This is creating a blob URL for me of the form blob:localhost:8000/some random sys__UUID

Is there a way to create a URL of the form localhost:8000/some random sys__UUID/myDocument.pdf?
(Without creating said file on the server)

Comment: Im with the same problem right now, did get a way to make it work?